# How can I populate a collection inside a DTO with LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dto

I created the following DTO:

```
    public class TestAndQuestionDTO
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int QuestionsCount { get; set; }
        public ICollection<TestAndQuestionDTO.Questions> TestQuestions { get; set; }

        public class Questions
        {
            public Guid QuestionUId { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to populate this with LINQ but I am stuck on how to populate the inner Questions class.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    var result = await db.Tests
            .Include(t => t.TestQuestions)
            .Where(t => t.TestId == id)
            .Select(t => new TestAndQuestionDTO
            {
                Name = t.Title,
                TestQuestions = new TestAndQuestionDTO.Questions
                {
                    QuestionUId = t.TestQuestions. ????
                }

            })
            .ToListAsync();
```

Can someone tell me how I can populate the TestQuestions collection field with the data that is brought back from my collection:  `.Include(t => t.TestQuestions)`  Do I have to for example have a constructor in the TestAndQuestionDTO to create a collection of TestQuestions?

Here's my Test class for reference:

```
public partial class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        this.TestQuestions = new HashSet<TestQuestion>();
    }

    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TestQuestion> TestQuestions { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Why can't you just do `TestQuestions = t.TestQuestions` in the select?

Comment: Because the TestQuestions class on the left just has one field and the t.TestQuestions has many fields. Correct me if I am wrong but I was thinking I should be mapping them all one to one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use another Select to convert into your Questions DTO like this:

```
var result = await db.Tests
        .Include(t => t.TestQuestions)
        .Where(t => t.TestId == id)
        .Select(t => new TestAndQuestionDTO
        {
            Name = t.Title,
            TestQuestions = t.TestQuestions.Select(tq => new TestAndQuestionDTO.Questions
            {
                QuestionUId = tq.QuestionUId,
                //fill in your Questions DTO here
            })

        })
        .ToListAsync();
```

If you need `TestAndQuestionDTO.Questions` to be an `ICollection<>` type, change it to this:

```
var result = await db.Tests
        .Include(t => t.TestQuestions)
        .Where(t => t.TestId == id)
        .Select(t => new TestAndQuestionDTO
        {
            Name = t.Title,
            TestQuestions = new Collection<TestAndQuestionDTO.Questions>(
                t.TestQuestions.Select(tq => new TestAndQuestionDTO.Questions
                {
                    QuestionUId = tq.QuestionUId,
                    //fill in your Questions DTO here
                }).ToList())
        })
        .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I am getting the error message: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WebRole1.Controllers.TestController.TestAndQuestionDTO.Questions>' to 
'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<WebRole1.Controllers.TestController.TestAndQuestionDTO.Questions>'.

Comment: Does `Test‌​AndQuestionDTO.Questions` have to be an `ICollection` instead of `IEnumerable`?

Comment: I prefer to work with `IEnumerable` so I would change it to that. Otherwise, I've made an addition to my answer.